# How can I list Drupal 8 Content Moderation draft

Tags: 8

I'm able to write a "draft" as an admin so it's visible as unpublished content on the content list.

The problem is that I can not make list visible to other "editors" (Who even can access the node as "draft" and even edit it and store again).

In short words admin only is able to view all contents including drafts, other user see only published contents.

How can I make people able to browse full content list, including the drafted nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, on Drupal, only users with the *Bypass content access control* permission can see every unpublished post, but that is a permission to give to a very small set of users, such as administrator users.
The other users can only see the unpublished nodes they created.

You can create a module that defines a new permission (e.g. *View unpublished content*), and implement [`hook_node_access_records_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records_alter/8.5.x)/[`hook_node_grants_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants_alter/8.5.x) to grant the view access to those users with the new permission.